# MVC DropDownList with Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, razor, html.dropdownlistfor, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlistfor

I need to display a DropDownList on my view, with the values of 2 different tables.

- Partner
- ServiceProvider

GET Edit

```
var partners = db.Partners.Include(p => p.Company);
            var serviceProviders = db.ServiceProvider.Include(f => f.Building);
            ViewBag.Assigned = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (var p in partners)
            {
                ViewBag.Assigned.Add("P_" + p.PartnerID.ToString(), p.Name);
            }
            foreach (var f in serviceProviders)
            {
                ViewBag.Assigned.Add("FS_" + f.ServiceProviderID.ToString(), f.Name);
            }
```

This Dictionary will hold key,value pairs that look like this:

- "P_1", "Abc"
- "P_2", "Def"
- "SP_1", "Ghi"
- "SP_2", "Jkl"
- "SP_3" "Mno"

POST Edit

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "ReqID,State,Title,Description,Emission,Severity,BuildingID,Appointment,CUICreator,Photo1,Photo2,Photo3,Photo4,Photo5,IDPartner,IDServiceProvider,IDColaborator,Assigned")] Req req)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(req).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.EdificioID = new SelectList(db.Buildings, "BuildingID", "Name", req.BuildingID);
            return View(req);
        }
```

On my Edit.cshtml, I tryed:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Assigned, new SelectList(ViewBag.Assigned, "Key", "Value"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

and

```
@Html.DropDownList("Atribuido", new SelectList(ViewBag.Atribuidos, "Key", "Value"))
```

and both of them give the same error:

```
O valor não pode ser nulo.
Nome do parâmetro: items

Descrição: Exceção não processada ao executar o pedido Web atual. Consulte o rastreio da pilha para obter mais informações sobre o erro e o respetivo ponto de origem no código.
```

which translates to this:

```
Value can not be null.
Parameter name: items

Description: Unhandled exception while executing the current Web request. See the stack trace for more information about the error and its source point in the code.
```

What would be the best way to do this task?

Answer (score 1):

That error message matches the message you'd get from an [`ArgumentNullException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception(v=vs.110).aspx) which is thrown when a method gets a null value for a required argument. I suspect the error is coming from the [`SelectList` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.) since it takes a parameter named `items`.  Since you don't set `ViewBag.Assigned` in your `Post` handler, the viewbag item is probabvly getting lost and is null when you try to render the edit view after a post.